# How to append a letter that comes after vowel letter to a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary where the keys are the letters 'a' and 'e'. If the character after 'a' or 'e' is a letter, then I want to append it to a list that shouldn't have repetitions.

```
text= 'there is a sea apple'
    a = []
    e = []
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if text[i+1].isalpha() and i == 'a':
            vowel_dict['a'] = []
            vowel_dict['a'].append(text[i])
        if text[i+1].isalpha() and i == 'e':
            vowel_dict['e'] = []
            vowel_dict['e'].append(text[i])
    print('vowel_dict)
```

I want my output to be:

```
{'a': ['p'], 'e': ['r', 'a']}
```

Comment: NB: a list without repetitions is a set, which also exist in Python.

Comment: Don't use `i == 'a'`, but `text[i] == 'a'`. As you do in the other half of the comparison.

Comment: Hi @canter129, please try to run your code and fix any errors that prevent it from running. If you're not sure how, use pythontutor.com.

Answer (score 1):

```
text= 'there is a sea apple'
    a = []
    e = []
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if text[i+1].isalpha() and i == 'a':
            vowel_dict['a'] = []
            vowel_dict['a'].append(text[i])
        if text[i+1].isalpha() and i == 'e':
            vowel_dict['e'] = []
            vowel_dict['e'].append(text[i])
    print('vowel_dict)
```

- produces an `IndentationError: unexpected indent` because your second and subsequent lines are one indentation level deeper than the previous line for no reason.
- Additionally: `print('vowel_dict)` produces a `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal` because `print(vowel_dict)`.
- Next you have an `IndexError: string index out of range` because on the last iteration of the for loop, `i == len(text) - 1` and `i + 1 == len(text)` is too big an integer to index into `text`. To fix this, `for i in range(len(text)):` should be `for i in range(len(text) - 1):`.
- After that you have `NameError: name 'vowel_dict' is not defined` because you never declare `vowel_dict`. You must declare a variable before using it. You can do so by doing `vowel_dict = {}` or `vowel_dict = dict()` (they're equivalent) before the for loop.

```
text= 'there is a sea apple'
a = []
e = []
vowel_dict = {}
for i in range(len(text) - 1):
    if text[i+1].isalpha() and i == 'a':
        vowel_dict['a'] = []
        vowel_dict['a'].append(text[i])
    if text[i+1].isalpha() and i == 'e':
        vowel_dict['e'] = []
        vowel_dict['e'].append(text[i])
print(vowel_dict)
```

Now you should be able to run your code, but it's still not doing the right thing. Play around with it.

---

Next time, please try to run your code and fix any errors preventing it from running. There are many places online where you can run your code: e.g. repl.it, pythontutor.com, thonny.org (the last two are particularly good for beginners).

---

Here's one way to do it:

```
s = 'there is a sea apple'
N = len(s)
a_successors = set()
e_successors = set()

for i in range(N-1):
    curr = s[i]
    after = s[i+1]
    if after.isalpha():
        if curr == 'a':
            a_successors.add(next_)
        elif curr == 'e':
            e_successors.add(next_)
vowel_dict = {'a': a_successors, 'e': e_successors}
print(vowel_dict)
```

prints:

```
{'a': {'p'}, 'e': {'r', 'a'}}
```

If you want `a_successors` and `e_successors` as lists, just do `list(a_successors`)`and likewise for`e_successors`.

Comment: Those are good points. Feel free to edit the answer and I'll accept the it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for that to simplify the code, although it can be less efficient:

```py
import re

text = 'there is a sea apple'

d = {k: set(re.findall(rf"{k}(\w)", text)) for k in 'ae'}
print(d) # {'a': {'p'}, 'e': {'r', 'a'}}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a dictionary with 'a' and 'e' as keys and sets as values.  In order to get each character and its successor you can use zip on the text.  Then check if the character is in the dictionary and its successor is a letter.  Adding the next letter to the set will ensure that each successor letter is going to be counted only once:

```
text= 'there is a sea apple'

result = {'a':set(), 'e':set()}     # set of successor letters for 'a' and 'e'
for v,n in zip(text,text[1:]):
    if v in result and n.isalpha(): # a/e followed by a letter ?
        result[v].add(n)            # add to key's set

print(result)
{'a': {'p'}, 'e': {'a', 'r'}}
```